# Calculate the range of items shown on each page using codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am building a website that will have a lot of paginated pages on it, with hundreds to thousands of items on it. I want to show the range of items shown on the current page like so:

|  115-130 out of 300 |

I have tried this but it does not work correctly

```
echo "Showing ".( $page == 1 ? 1 : ($page -1) * $config["per_page"] +1 )." to ".($page *  $config["per_page"])." item of ".$config["total_rows"];
```

The current code in my controller is:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("pagination");
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('status_model');//load the status model

    //pagination config
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = site_url() . "/home/index";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->status_model->count_active_entries();//Get the total number of rows
    $config["per_page"] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config["anchor_class"] = 'class="normal" ';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="num_active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $statuses = $this->status_model->get_entries($config["per_page"], $page); //call the method to get all the active statuses

    if($statuses !== false) { 

        $content_data['results'] = $statuses;
    }
    else { // If no results are returned display the following error message

        $content_data['error'] = 'Error no status updates are being returned from the database. Please contact an administrator.';
    }

    echo "Showing ".( $page == 1 ? 1 : ($page -1) * $config["per_page"] +1 )." to ".($page * $config["per_page"])." item of ".$config["total_rows"];


    $content_data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['title'] = ' Status';                           //Browser page title
    $data['page_title'] = 'The Latest Status Updates';//The page H1 tag
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('results', $content_data, TRUE);//the page content

    $this->load->view('home', $data);                  

}
```

Comment: `it doesn't work correctly gives us no info` what actually it outputs?

Comment: hey i did in another way of representation like this........first 1 2 3 4 last .......these are button for pages.......if you want this kind of pagination i will help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all Try after remove following line

```
echo "Showing ".( $page == 1 ? 1 : ($page -1) * $config["per_page"] +1 )." to ".($page * $config["per_page"])." item of ".$config["total_rows"];
```

And check your page.
If your page is rendering without error and pagination is working fine then you should calculte the range by counting fetched rows and pass the calculated range to view.

```
 $count = count($statuses);
 $r_from = $page <= 1 ? 1 : ($page -1) * $config["per_page"]+1; //RANGE STARTS FROM 
 $r_to   = $r_from + $count - 1;    //RANGE ENDS TO
 $content_data["range"] = $count? "Showing ".$r_from." to ".$r_to." item of ".$config["total_rows"]:'';
```

On your view print it as you are printing the $content_data["links"];
May be something like

```
echo $range;
```

complete controller code-

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("pagination");
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('status_model');//load the status model

    //pagination config
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = site_url() . "/home/index";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->status_model->count_active_entries();//Get the total number of rows
    $config["per_page"] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config["anchor_class"] = 'class="normal" ';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="num_active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $statuses = $this->status_model->get_entries($config["per_page"], $page); //call the method to get all the active statuses
    $count = '';
    if($statuses !== false) { 

        $content_data['results'] = $statuses;
        $count = count($statuses);
        $r_from = $page <= 1 ? 1 : ($page -1) * $config["per_page"]+1;
        $r_to   = $r_from + $count - 1;
        // YOU CAN DO IT WITHOUT COUNT. FOR THAT YOU NEED TO CALCULATE $r_to 
        // $r_to = $page * $config["per_page"];
        // AND NEED TO CHECK THIS WITH Total record
        // $r_to = $r_to>$config["total_rows"] ? $config["total_rows"]:$r_to;
    }
    else { // If no results are returned display the following error message

        $content_data['error'] = 'Error no status updates are being returned from the database. Please contact an administrator.';
    }


    $content_data["range"] = $count? "Showing ".$r_from." to ".$r_to." item of ".$config["total_rows"]:'';

    $content_data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['title'] = ' Status';                           //Browser page title
    $data['page_title'] = 'The Latest Status Updates';//The page H1 tag
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('results', $content_data, TRUE);//the page content

    $this->load->view('home', $data);                  

}
```